# how to fix PM2 error on run a npm script?

Tags: node.js, pm2

When i try command npm install pm2 -m, i get this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crsYd.jpg)

i try reload and update nod, but this didn’t help

Comment: Do you have NPM and NODE installed on your os? And what OS do you use, Ubuntu or Mac

Comment: Are you running the command as a `root` user?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also, update node from your current version 8.10 to any of version 10.0+ as it is required by the package you are attempting to install. You can update node by `npm update -g node` or install latest by `npm install -g node`, or use a version manager, e.g., `nvm` (recommended).